# Relative Import In Unittest

Tags: python, path, reference

I have reviewed several posts re: Relative vs Absolute imports, but none of the solutions proposed seemed to solve my problem.

I have a directory structure like the following:

```
--src
    --dir1
        --signal
            __init__.py
            parent_class.py
            --hf
                __init__.py
                child_class.py
                child_class_tests.py
```

The import within `child_class.py` for the parent class is as follows `from ..parent_class import Parent`

If I execute the `child_class_tests.py` with the pycharm Run configuration with a script path of: `C:\test\src\dir1\signal\hf\child_class_tests.py` with a working directory of `C:\test\src\dir1\signal\hf\` I get the exception: `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

within `child_class_tests.py` I have the following code:

```
import unittest
import pandas as pd
import sys
import os
print(os.getcwd())
from child_class import Child


class TestSignals(unittest.TestCase):

    DATA = pd.read_pickle(r'data.pkl')

    def test_child_class(self):
        """
        Test 
        """
        test_set = self.DATA.copy()

        print(test_set.head())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The error occurs on the attempted `from child_class import Child` on `from ..parent import Parent` within the Child class definition.

I have tried adding absolute references as well as running from the higher directory and neither have worked.  I'm using Python 3.9 with PyCharm 2021.1.1.

In following the other posts, I've tried to recreate the environments that they're referencing and have been unable to rectify the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`child_class` is being treated as a top-level module not contained in any package, i.e. it is found in the directory `src/dir1/signal/hf` (which appears in `sys.path` implicitly as `''`), not the package `dir1.signal.hf`.

Your tests should not import it like this, but rather from the package it belongs to (and your test runner should thus be configured to know where to find `dir1`):

```
import unittest
import pandas as pd

from dir1.signal.hf.child_class import Child


class TestSignals(unittest.TestCase):

    DATA = pd.read_pickle(r'data.pkl')

    def test_child_class(self):
        """
        Test 
        """
        test_set = self.DATA.copy()

        print(test_set.head())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

---

PEP 366 also suggests the following instead of modifying the import, which may work (though I haven't tested it):

```
if __name__ == '__main__' and __package__ is None:
    __package__ = 'dir1.signal.hf'
```

You still need to ensure that `src` is on the search path in order to find `dir1`, so I think I would still recommend modifying the import instead.

Comment: excellent explanation.  I understand now and have fixed the issue.  Thanks for the help.